# How to change the value of cells in a range with data validation when the value of any of the cells in that same range changes

Tags: excel, vba, validation, excel-formula

I am creating a checklist in Excel for enemy encounters (formations) in a RPG game.

The checklist is a two column table, in which each cell of Column A uses a data validation list with values ✔, ✘ and R. Column B contains all the enemy formations in chronological order, including repeated formations that appear at different moments of the game. Each formation has a corresponding Column A cell.

All values in Column A are preset to ✘. When the player encounters a formation, they can select ✔.
The value in Column A is used by a formula in another cell that becomes GREEN when all the possible formations have been marked as ✔ or R.

However, as mentioned, the list contains repeated formations, so if the player misses one (won't mark it as ✔), they may meet the same formation later in the game, and be able to mark it as ✔ then.

What I want (and haven't been able to do) is either one of the following different solutions:
(I'm using an example formation for clarity)

IDEAL SOLUTION

- When the player marks *any* of the Goblin x 2 formations as ✔, all other values in Column A corresponding to Goblin x 2 formations that are not the one marked as ✔ become R.

GOOD SOLUTION

- When the player marks *any* of the Goblin x 2 formations as ✔, all other values corresponding to Goblin x 2 formations become ✔.

A SOLUTION

- Any idea is very much pretty welcomed.

Tried with Conditional formatting. Wrong alley.

Found this formula =IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Formation"},A1))),"✔","") but wasn't able to tweak it to do what I need. And I also encountered the problem of data validation restrictions.

Now I'm experimenting with named ranges. Maybe I should use VBA? I don't know much about that, but I'd be willing to research if I'd knew where to start for this particular problem.

ChatGPT wasn't really useful. It suggested to use the simple =A1, =A2, etc. So yeah.. not great. (Probably didn't use the right prompt).

Thanks!

Comment: ChatGPT - have to ask the right question, but based on the results seen on here it is cr*p at writing code.

Comment: @SolarMike: What do you mean by that? You think that this question was generated by ChatGPT?

Comment: @z I meant exactly what I wrote, are you making assumptions?

Comment: I read your question, but something missing here: 1) You speak for two columns the A with List of three symbols, and the B with "formations".2) Then you say about "chronological order", where is this information recorded? 3) In your example you say "Goblin x 2 formations" the information ""Goblin x 2"" that is recorded? and the last and most important: You indicate the ideal solution and the good solution, but it seems that you have not written a single line of code. You can post your attempt and a picture of the sheet so you can be helped more easily?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ΑΓΡΙΑΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ The chronological order is not recorded anywhere, it's just the order in which the formations are sorted in Column B. B1 contains the first formation the player encounters in the game; B2, the second; B3, the third, etc. So, for instance, B3 can contain the same formation as B27, B78 and B103, since the player can encounter the same formation later in the game. As for the code, I have written several formulas trying to achieve this, but none of them were useful. The only one it was somewhat useful is included in my question: =IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Formation"},A1))),"✔","")

Comment: @SolarMike My bad. I am extremely new to programming and code. I thought it was an easy task but it wasn't. I don't even know how to ask the correct questions to ChatGPT. I researched a lot before asking here, but then I wasn't even sure if I was researching the correct information. I mean, I'm not even sure if this is the correct question. I did my best, but yeah.. I guess for programmers this is just cringe. Thanks for your input nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use VBA for this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    Dim ColA As Range: Set ColA = Me.Range(Me.Range("A1"), Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    Dim ColB As Range: Set ColB = ColA.Offset(0, 1)
    Dim TargetFiltered As Range: Set TargetFiltered = Application.Intersect(ColA, target)
    If Not TargetFiltered Is Nothing Then
        Dim TargetCell As Range: For Each TargetCell In TargetFiltered.Cells
            If TargetCell.Value = "T" Then
                Dim Formation As Variant: Formation = TargetCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                Dim r As Long: For r = 1 To ColA.Rows.Count
                    If ColA.Row + r - 1 <> TargetCell.Row Then
                        If ColA.Cells(r, 2).Value = Formation Then
                            If ColA.Cells(r, 1).Value = "F" Then
                                ColA.Cells(r, 1).Value = "R"
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

I substituted checkmark with "T" and cross with "F" because I don't know how you implemented them.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure how to even read that code, but it will certainly give me a lot of paths to start researching and learning about it. TYVM